# How to exclude files from a Jenkins pipeline "scm checkout" step?

Tags: svn, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkins multibranch pipeline, I'd like to exclude some folders from a SVN checkout, that are not useful for the build.

I currently use the following:

```groovy
stage('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
}
```

We can add parameters to the "checkout scm" step but I can't find how to specify SVN exclusion pattern?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a normal SVN checkout (I mean outside Jenkins), can you ?

Comment: I thought it was possible but indeed it seems not possible. I have three top level folders in my SVN repository and I only need two of them, is it possible to perform two "checkout scm" for each directory I need instead?